# How to detect memory leak using LeakCanary in fragment with modular code?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, leakcanary

I have an application with multiple modules. Say module `app` and `core`.

I have created MyApplication class in `app` module and have overridden the required code for LeakCanary. But I am unable to link the code with fragments present in my second module `core`.

How can I detect memory leak in fragments present in `core` module?

Comment: Add leak canary as a dependency in the second module.

Comment: I'm not sure if this works. I have tried it, but it does not detect even those leaks which were identified while I added LeakCanary in `app` module. Note that activities are also in second module whose leaks were identified while I add LeakCanary in first module.

Answer (score 0):

With latest leakcanary release, they have introduced support for fragments of Support Library. We need to declare below dependency in out build.gradle to have it.

```
debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-support-fragment:1.6.1'
```